# Execute external program with PHP and arguments

Tags: php

I wish to run external program with PHP and provide some arguments, like:

`exec('C:\\Program Files\\iNFekt\\infekt\\infekt-cmd.exe -S --utf-16 '.$nfoFile, $output, $return_var);`

But nothing happens, `$output` is empty array, `$return_var` is 1

What is my mistake here ?

Comment: What does `infekt-cmd.exe` do? Does it prints something to the output?

Comment: Yes, print that file is saved as xxx.nfo

Comment: Try the code in my answer.

Comment: `excel` will print the output exactly the same as the output you would see if you have execute the command from the command line. So, are you sure the program you are trying to execute return something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell-exec) to get the output:

```
$output = shell_exec('C:\\Program Files\\iNFekt\\infekt\\infekt-cmd.exe -S --utf-16 '.$nfoFile');
```

From the [`Manual`](http://php.net/shell-exec):

> shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string